# Hide "sending message" dialog in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I don't want to see thunderbirds "sending message". It's too slow, I'd rather continue answering emails.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be easily done in config editor:

navigate to

> Tools > Options > Advanced > Config Editor > "I'll be
>   careful, I promise!"

then search for parameter

> mailnews.show_send_progress

and change the value to `false`

then search for

> mailnews.sendInBackground

and change the value to `true`

restart `Thunderbird`

voila! its gone

Comment: now it's just in the bottom of the screen - it takes just the same amount of time for me to **wait** until I can close the window. Maybe a workaround would be to set AHK to make ctrl+enter send a message and then hide the window?

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your additional question. You will have to also set **mailnews.sendInBackground** to **true**

Comment: Note: This article suggests you should also set `offline.send.unsent_messages 1`: https://www.summet.com/blog/2015/11/16/making-thunderbird-send-messages-in-the-background-like-outlook/